# Getting No mapping found for HTTP request with URI

Tags: java, spring, servlets

I am trying to handle Requests in Spring dispatcher servlet.

My web.xml is having the servlet:

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>ApplicationDispatcher</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/SpringConfig/WebApplication.xml</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>2</load-on-startup>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>ApplicationDispatcher</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.json</url-pattern>
    <url-pattern>*.do</url-pattern>
    <url-pattern>/entities/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

My controller looks :

```
@Controller(value="entities")
public class EntitiesController {
    private static final Logger LOGGER = Logger.getLogger(EntitiesController.class);

    @Autowired
    private IEntityDataService iEntityDataService;

    @RequestMapping("/list")
    public String displayAllEntities() {
        LOGGER.info("Displaying entity dashboard");
        return "entity_landing";
    }

    @RequestMapping("/display")
    public String displayCheckpointDashboard(Integer id) {
        LOGGER.info("Displaying checkpoint dashboard for id " + id);
        return "entity";
    }

    @RequestMapping("/update")
    public String displayUpdateEntity(Integer id) {
        System.out.println("Update id " + id);
        return "new_entity";
    }

    @RequestMapping("/add")
    public String displayNewEntity() {
        LOGGER.info("Displaying new entity page");
        return "new_entity";
    }
}
```

I am seeing the following logs in my application log:

```
2016-01-13 16:15:12 INFO  RequestMappingHandlerMapping:180 - Mapped "{[/entity/add/entityDetails.do],methods=[GET],params=[],headers=[],consumes=[],produces=[],custom=[]}" onto public java.lang.String com.test.EntityController.saveEntityDetails(com.test.vo.EntityCheckpointsVo)
2016-01-13 16:15:12 INFO  RequestMappingHandlerMapping:180 - Mapped "{[/entities/list],methods=[],params=[],headers=[],consumes=[],produces=[],custom=[]}" onto public java.lang.String com.test.EntitiesController.displayAllEntities()
2016-01-13 16:15:12 INFO  RequestMappingHandlerMapping:180 - Mapped "{[/entities/add],methods=[],params=[],headers=[],consumes=[],produces=[],custom=[]}" onto public java.lang.String com.test.EntitiesController.displayNewEntity()
2016-01-13 16:15:12 INFO  DispatcherServlet:476 - FrameworkServlet 'ApplicationDispatcher': initialization completed in 950 ms
2016-01-13 16:15:12 WARN  PageNotFound:1116 - No mapping found for HTTP request with URI [/TestProject/entities/add] in DispatcherServlet with name 'ApplicationDispatcher'
2016-01-13 16:15:17 WARN  PageNotFound:1116 - No mapping found for HTTP request with URI [/TestProject/entities/add] in DispatcherServlet with name 'ApplicationDispatcher'
2016-01-13 16:17:04 WARN  PageNotFound:1116 - No mapping found for HTTP request with URI [/TestProject/entities/add] in DispatcherServlet with name 'ApplicationDispatcher'
```

I am not having any clue as the log says there is `/entities/add` is registered. I am able to access other URL such as localhost:8080/TestProject/entity/add/entityDetails.do but I am not able to access localhost:8080/TestProject/entities/add.

Please help me out here.

Thanks

Update :

Snippet from EntityController

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping(value = "/entity")
public class EntityController {
    @RequestMapping(value = "/add/entityDetails.do", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String saveEntityDetails(EntityCheckpointsVo entityCheckpointsVo) {
        return "success";
    }
}
```

Comment: I think the problem will be resolved once you mention / in servletMapping instead of entities.

Comment: Could it be undeclared HTTP methods ? I see "methods=[]" in your logs .

Comment: @Berger in that case spring will tell method not supported

Comment: I note that you're not using the base `/` for your mappings for the dispatcher servlet itself, and you have multiple *kinds* of mapping patterns. Why, and  would it be possible to just use Spring Boot and skip the complication of the `web.xml` entirely?

Comment: @Jango: When I mention / as url mapping, then `/TestProject/index.html` is not getting mapped.

Comment: change `@RequestMapping("/entities")` to `@RequestMapping("/TestProject/entities")` or change `<url-pattern>/entities/*</url-pattern>` to `<url-pattern>/TestProject/entities/*</url-pattern>` in web.xml

Comment: @Braj no, it's just a context...

Comment: @NewUser can you share your other controller (`EntityController`)? It seems this one is working, so it may help...

Comment: Use `/` base url pattern in web.xml and define request mapping for `/` to server`index.html` that's the only issue as you commented about index.html

Comment: can you hit this url localhost:8080/TestProject/entities/entities/add and tell what the status is

Comment: @premkumar: this is in a question `...but I am not able to access localhost:8080/TestProject/entities/add` I cannot see the difference of what you are asking...

Comment: @Betlista check my answer.

Comment: Sorry, I missed doubled entities part...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you try hitting following url, it will work.

```
localhost:8080/TestProject/entities/entities/add
```

This is because the first "entities" in the url is getting consumed because of /entities/* pattern in web.xml . After consuming this string then remaining path uri goes to dispatcher. In this case, entities/add goes to dispatcher and it works fine.

```
localhost:8080/TestProject/entities/add
```

Whereas for the url mentioned by you "entities" gets consumed and only "add" is left for which dispatcher does not have mapping.

If you have a servlet mapping like following:

```
<url-pattern>/abc/def/*</url-pattern>
```

then in general for any spring request mapping with this pattern, url will be like:

```
localhost:8080/TestProject/abc/def/{custom request mapping}
```

For the url /entities/add request mapping, it will be:

```
localhost:8080/TestProject/abc/def/entities/add
```

**Relevant class,method names and code snippets to show where consumptions happens from spring source code.**

I could not find links. Therefore I went straight into the code. If you traverse these mentioned classes and methods in order you can see as to why it is consuming from path uri:

Snippets from Dispatcher Servlet and related classes:
1.   org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet **getHandler(HttpServletRequest request)** 
2.   org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.AbstractHandlerMapping **getHandler(HttpServletRequest request)** 
3.   org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.AbstractHandlerMapping **getHandlerExecutionChain(Object handler, HttpServletRequest request)**
 String lookupPath = this.urlPathHelper.getLookupPathForRequest(request);

4.   org.springframework.web.util.UrlPathHelper **getLookupPathForRequest(HttpServletRequest request)**   . Default value of this.alwaysUseFullPath=false is false. There consuming from path uri happens. You can the variable **"rest"** which will contain our spring request mapping like /entities/add in this post. 
5.   org.springframework.web.util.UrlPathHelper **getPathWithinServletMapping(HttpServletRequest request)** String path = getRemainingPath(pathWithinApp, servletPath, false);

```
public String getLookupPathForRequest(HttpServletRequest request) {
    // Always use full path within current servlet context?
    if (this.alwaysUseFullPath) {  // default this.alwaysUseFullPath=false
        return getPathWithinApplication(request);
    }
    // Else, use path within current servlet mapping if applicable
    String rest = getPathWithinServletMapping(request);
    if (!"".equals(rest)) {
        return rest;
    }
    else {
        return getPathWithinApplication(request);
    }
}
```

From here you can easily go deeper to find how it is consuming from path uri.

Comment: Are you sure it is consumed? And `*.do` is not consumed?

Comment: the last entry will not get consumed like the *.do

Comment: check the last post in this  link http://www.coderanch.com/t/640094/Spring/Multiple-Dispatcher-Servlet . Trying to find a better link

Comment: I just tested it on my own and you re correct, it is consumed.

Comment: i have edited my answer. it now has name of classes, methods and some snippets to show where in the code this consumption happens. If you are interested you can have a look

Comment: @Betlista : Yes the *.do is getting consumed.

Comment: @NewUser I'm surprised, because you wrote, that `localhost:8080/TestProject/entity/add/entityDetails.do` works... If consumed it should not work, right?

Comment: @Betlista : Sorry .. Din't get "consume" my bad

Comment: @NewUser can you check if the url , localhost:8080/TestProject/entities/entities/add , worked or not?

Answer (score 1):

I can see the difference now...

```
@Controller(value="entities")
public class EntitiesController {
```

vs

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping(value = "/entity")
public class EntityController {
```

You do not have `RequestMapping` in `EntitiesController`... As you know probably, `value` in `@Controller` is logical name of the component...

**Note:** Based on [prem kumar's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34765828/384674) I'm not sure whether this is a mistake or a design...